# .NET 8 Microsoft Docker Image: Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070008

Tags: .net, docker, ubuntu, .net-core, docker-compose

I upgraded my project to .NET 8 today; I followed the [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) on migrating from .NET 7 to .NET 8. However, upon deploying the application, I've encountered a problem.

Locally, the solution builds and runs fine. However, on my Ubuntu server, when I run `docker-compose up -d` my MVC application container fails. When I look at the logs via `docker logs <container id>` I simply see:

> Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070008

I did some Googling and noticed some were saying to add `ENV COMPlus_EnableDiagnostics=0` which I did, but that made no difference.

I'm not sure what to do now; everything seems to be OK.

The code is open-source, here is the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/bejebeje/blob/main/Bejebeje.Mvc/Dockerfile). And here is what I have in my docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  bejebeje-mvc:
    image: bejebeje/mvc:latest
    ports:
      - "5010:5005"
    env_file:
      - ./variables.env
    depends_on:
      - bejebeje-main-db
  bejebeje-main-db:
    image: postgres:12.4
    ports:
      - "8002:5432"
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./variables.env

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: bejebeje_net

volumes:
  data-volume:
```

What am I missing?

Comment: There was a breaking change - [New non-root 'app' user in Linux images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/app-user) maybe this behaviour is related to the non-root user. Can you please provide a [mre]? There is nothing peculiar I see out of the box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed it by upgrading Docker Engine on my Ubuntu server.

The server was running Docker Engine version 20.xxx, but the latest version was 24.xxx

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same error during upgrade from .NET 6 and .NET 7 projects to .NET 8.

Everything works fine on Windows, but on Linux server I'm still receiving next message:

> Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070008
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c
> dotnet restore "Project/Project.csproj" --configfile "./Nuget.config"'
> returned a non-zero code: 137
>
> ERROR: Job failed: exit code 137

I have Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Tried these approaches:

1. `ENV COMPlus_EnableDiagnostics=0`;
2. inside of docker-compose.yml:

   security_opt:

   - seccomp=unconfined
3. Upgraded version of Docker from 20.10.X to 25.0.3

And still trying to fix it. I will provide updates.

Comment: I'm running into this as well after upgrading to dotnet 8. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing images to alpine images.
Also tried option `ENV COMPlus_EnableDiagnostics=0` but it didn't help.